# On Select Event Another drop down appears

Tags: javascript, html

is it possible to create below scenario using Javascript:

I have a drop down box "Deposit Type" which has 2 options: "Envelop" and "Enhanced". and what i want is when I select Envelop from drop down list another check box should appear as "Dispensing".

```
<select id="DepositType" name="nmf" style="float:left;">
    <option value="Envelope">Principal</option>
    <option value="Enhanced">Producer</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you need a new checkbox to appear ?

Comment: @surendran: Hi Thanks for replying on the query and i can see the demo is working fine, But why i am getting Error "The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object" when i am putting whole code in html page?

Comment: @user3103991 surendran (and LorDex) assumed you're using the jQuery library, not plain javascript

Comment: thanks lzkata, @user3103991 do you want me to update the answer with javascript.

Comment: Yes @surendran that will be so help full, I am newbie with javascript and jquery so can't find out the solution.

Comment: @user3103991 I am updating the fiddle.

Comment: @user3103991 I have updated my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select#DepositType').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'Envelope') {
  //do something
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PV52L/

```
document.getElementById("DepositType").onchange = function(event) {
if (event.target.value == "Envelope")
    document.body.innerHTML += '<input type="checkbox" name="Dispensing" value="Dispensing">Dispensing<br>';
};
```